# How to move elements in an array, putting odds to the beginning of the array (smallest to largest), and evens to the back ( largest to smallest )

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, element

I have to write a functioncalled moveAndSortInt() that will receive an array of integers as an argument, and move all the even values down to the second half of the array and sort them from largest to smallest, while all the odd values will be sorted from smallest to largest. How can I improve my code?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void moveAndSortInt(int[], int);
void displayName(); 

int main() {

    int ary1[] = { -19, 270, 76, -61, 54 };

    int size = 5;

    int i;

    int ary2[] = {9, 8, -103, -73, 74, 53};

    int size2 = 6;

    int j;




    displayName();

    cout << endl;

    cout << "Original ary1[]" << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << "  " << ary1[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "\nCallingMoveAndSortInt() --\n " << endl;

    moveAndSortInt(ary1, size);

    cout << "Updated ary1[]" << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << "  " << ary1[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;

    cout << "\nOriginal ary2[]" << endl;

    for (j = 0; j < size2; j++) {
        cout << "  " << ary2[j] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;

    cout << "\nCallingMoveAndSortInt() --\n" << endl;

    moveAndSortInt(ary2, size2);

    cout << "Updated ary2[]" << endl;

    for (j = 0; j < size2; j++) {
        cout << "  " << ary2[j] << " ";
   }
}


void moveAndSortInt(int ary[], int size) {
    int i, j;
    int temp;

    for (i = 0; i < 1 + size / 2; i++) {
        if (ary[i] % 2 == 0) {

            for (j = size - 1; j > size / 2; j--) {

                if (ary[j] % 2 != 0) {
                    temp = ary[i]; 
                    ary[i] = ary[j];
                    ary[j] = temp; 

                     j = 0;

                }
            }
        }
    }

    return;
```

Comment: You're not using `std::sort`. That would be a vast improvement.

Comment: we are not allowed to use any other methods, only our own logic

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: in that case, try using the *idea* of a **comparison function** that completely specifies the desired ordering. i.e. abstract that part out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for a code review "how can I improve my code" without citing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I looked at it a bit. Let's start with conventions.

```
int i;
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
```

Can be shortened to:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
```

Which looks better and is more readable. It would also be nice to have a few more comments, but that's something everyone needs to get better at, no matter how good they are.

So it seems that your code does correctly sort the array into even and odd halves. That's all you need to do yourself as long as you know where they end because sorting them largest to smallest is something that [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) can do for you.

Edit: It was pointed out to me that my previous example is not exactly the same, as with the second one i can only be used in the loop. For your purposes, they work the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `std::sort`, the standard algorithm for sorting, which is often implemented with a [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). It is very fast, and also supports custom comparison. Here's some code to get you started:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{

    std::vector<int> data = { 2, 213, 2, 2, 3 ,123, 4, 213, 2132, 123 };

    std::sort(data.begin(), data.end(), [](int lhs, int rhs)
    {
        if (lhs % 2) // if lhs is odd
            if (rhs % 2) // and rhs is odd then just use comparision
                return lhs < rhs; 
            else // and if rhs is even then rhs is "bigger"
                return false;
        else // if lhs is even
            if (rhs % 2)
                return true; // and rhs is odd then lhs is "bigger"
            else // and if they are both even just use comparision.
                return lhs < rhs;
    });
}
```

I'm sorry if that code is a little hard to read, but it does the trick.

This of course would work with C-style arrays too, just replace `data.begin()` with `data` and `data.end()` with `data + size`.

Comment: This is a 3 liner: `auto it = std::partition(data.begin(), data.end(), [](int n){return n%2;}); std::sort(data.begin(), it); std::sort(it,data.end(), std::greater<int>());`

Comment: mine doesn't require the extra O(N) operation, which yours does. +1 for simplicity though.

Comment: I understand that.  However if you read the OP's question, and look at the code I provided, it does exactly as was described, step by step (obvious so much that not even a comment is needed).  Kind of hard to figure out "on sight" what your solution is doing (again, nothing wrong with it -- it's that it is not obvious as to what it is doing).

Answer (score 0):

You can just reorder it

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    auto const shuffle = [] (int input)
    {
        if ( input % 2 )
        {
            unsigned const dist_from_min = (unsigned)input - INT_MIN;
            return dist_from_min >> 1;
        }
        else
        {
            unsigned const dist_from_max = INT_MAX - (unsigned)input;
            return INT_MIN + (dist_from_max >> 1);
        }
    };

    auto const ordering = [shuffle] (int left, int right)
        { return shuffle (left) < shuffle (right); };

    std::vector <int> data =
        { 5, 2, 3, 0, -1, -3, 1, 100
        , INT_MIN, INT_MIN + 1, INT_MAX, INT_MAX - 1
        , -567, -765, 765, 567, -234, -432, 234, 432
        };

    std::sort ( data.begin ( ), data.end ( ), ordering );

    for ( auto item : data )
        std::cout << item << "\n";
}
```